# Eclipse freeze accessing project -> properties -> android tab

Tags: android, eclipse, properties, freeze

Like the question says, no mater what project i try this on, old or brand new, when I right click on the project and go to properties, then select the Android tab (I want to add a library), Eclipse freezes.  I have to kill it.  Has anyone run into this problem or know how I might fix it?

Thanks

EDIT:

Eclipse SDK
Version: 3.6.2
Build id: M20110210-1200

EDIT:
Or is there another way to add a library.  I want to try out ActionbarSherlock :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Ok, so I don't claim to understand it, but I've tried it more than once and confirmed it.  When I'd go to the Android tab in Properties, the window automatically stretches the full height of my monitor and freezes.  So, I killed it and went back in, but this time, starting on a different category ("Resource" in this case), I squashed the window height down to almost as small as it could get and clicked on Android.  It worked.  Didn't freeze.  Then I was able to expand the window to see the list of libraries.  No idea what it is, but I did it several times...recreating the freeze and then the fix.  Hopefully this will save someone else...

Comment: Your solution is working but I want to know there is any logical reason why this is happen and 1+ for answer.

Answer (score 4):

i have found the reason ,because the list of available Android sdk is too long ,the window of the property can't be drawn immediately ,so it has no response.
the solution is open the SDK Manager ,delete the old sdk platform ,such as 1.5 1.6 3.0 3.1 3.2
those are not used usualy.then restart the eclipse .it works now .

Comment: Very well-researched, and probably the best explanation for the cause of this bug.

Comment: Confirmed as a valid solution to the problem. This should probably be reported to the makers of the Android SDK plugin...

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of problems you have to try the following (in the same order) and stop when it works.

1. Play around inside eclipse by closing and opening project, deleting and reimporting projects etc.,
2. Restart eclipse
3. Restart system
4. Upgrade to the latest android SDK
5. Upgrade to the latest eclipse version

Usually you should stop at 2. Sometimes you need to stop at 3. Occasionally at 4 and Rarely at 5.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the basic stuff.  I've done all of the 5.  This has been like this for a couple weeks now at least, I just haven't had a real need to get into the Android tab until now.