# Eclipse keep crashing when I go to properties?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, crash, android-actionbar

I'am trying to add an open source action bar (https://github.com/johannilsson/android-action bar) to my project and all you have to do is import the action bar project to eclipse then go to the tool bar Then  Project > Properties > Android and when ever I click the android tab at the side eclipse closes can you tell me why? and how to fix it please and thank you.

Comment: If you're not receiving any explicit errors on your screen its really hard to tell. Within the Eclipse install directory are there any log files?

Comment: @Alex can I do that without deleting all my config and plugins?

Comment: On Windows i've had issues installing addons when I don't run Eclipse as an Administrator (Right click -> Launch as Admin). In the past I've gotten really weird errors and behavior depending on the package. Give that a try if you haven't already.

Comment: @TheCapn same thing it stopped responding

Comment: @Alex re installed same problem!

Comment: My suspicion is that it is something with your specific configuration. The repo on github doesn't show anyone else having those issues, you may want to contact the author in this case to see what sort of troubleshooting they can provide you: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/issues

Comment: @TheCapn I don't think its the project because I tried viewing the properties for other projects I have in eclipse and same thing happens I'm just gonna delete everything and download again thanks for your help guys :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse freeze accessing project -> properties -> android tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059595/eclipse-freeze-accessing-project-properties-android-tab)

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate of this question: Eclipse freeze accessing project -> properties -> android tab

The gist of it is, select another category first before Android, resize the window, and then select Android. Seems like it's a common bug