# Eclipse for Android not responding when I try to open project settings

Tags: android, eclipse, properties

I am using Eclipse 4.2 Juno with Android SDK and for WIndows 7 32 bit. It crashes when I try to change the APIs for an android project. Here are the steps:
1. I right click on the project and press Properties.
2. I click on Android tab in the left.
3. Eclipse is not responding.

Any ideas why is that happening and how can I fixed? I tried it with two, three projects and it is the same for all.

Comment: Delete your eclipse DL and start again tbh ...

Comment: Try to remove completely android SDK and install again.

Comment: Switch to a new workspace and import your project from existing source.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this question: [Eclipse freeze accessing project -> properties -> android tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059595/eclipse-freeze-accessing-project-properties-android-tab)

The gist of it is, select another category first before Android, resize the window, and then select Android. Seems like it's a common bug