# Eclipse SDK crash

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Every time I access any of my **Android project's properties**, and go to the `Android` option, the SDK seems to crash. The strange thing about this is that it only crashes when I try to use that option, it works very well on other selections ... like the `Android Lint Properties`,`Builders`,`Java Build Path` ... etc. Help please.

Comment: I think I found my answer through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059595/eclipse-freeze-accessing-project-properties-android-tab) ...

Answer (score 1):

What does the Eclipse error log say?

The log is accessible one of two ways:

Help > About Eclipse > Configuration Details > View Error Log

The location of the file is `workspaceLoaction/.metadata/.log`

Comment: `!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-03-27 10:10:21.126
!MESSAGE Warnings while parsing the viewer contributions from the 'org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus' extension point
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-03-27 10:10:21.126
!MESSAGE invalid keybinding: Cannot bind to an incomplete key sequence: plug-in='org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui', id='AUTOGEN:::org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui.CEditorRulerActions/org.eclipse.cdt.debug.internal.ui.actions.CBreakpointPropertiesRulerActionDelegate'` ... and so on

Comment: Sorry, I found the same error message with Google, but I can't make heads or tail of a solution. If I were you, I'd create a new workspace with a new "Hello World" android application. If the problem does not show up with the new project, then I'd re-import all the projects in one go, importing files only, checking the box to copy them to the new workspace, taking care not to copy their .project file by unchecking that checkbox for each project. Of course, I'd try importing one project first to see if that works.

Comment: I think I found my answer through this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059595/eclipse-freeze-accessing-project-properties-android-tab) ...